# In awk, how can I use a file containing multiple format strings with printf?

Tags: awk, printf

I have a case where I want to use input from a file as the format for `printf()` in awk.  My formatting works when I set it in a string within the code, but it doesn't work when I load it from input.

Here's a tiny example of the problem:

```
$ # putting the format in a variable works just fine:
$ echo "" | awk -vs="hello:\t%s\n\tfoo" '{printf(s "bar\n", "world");}'
hello:  world
        foobar
$ # But getting the format from an input file does not.
$ echo "hello:\t%s\n\tfoo" | awk '{s=$0; printf(s "bar\n", "world");}'
hello:\tworld\n\tfoobar
$
```

So ... format substitutions work ("`%s`"), but not special characters like tab and newline.  Any idea why this is happening?  And is there a way to "do something" to input data to make it usable as a format string?

**UPDATE #1:**

As a further example, consider the following using bash heretext:

```
[me@here ~]$ awk -vs="hello: %s\nworld: %s\n" '{printf(s, "foo", "bar");}' <<<""
hello: foo
world: bar
[me@here ~]$ awk '{s=$0; printf(s, "foo", "bar");}' <<<"hello: %s\nworld: %s\n"
hello: foo\nworld: bar\n[me@here ~]$
```

As far as I can see, the same thing happens with multiple different awk interpreters, and I haven't been able to locate any documentation that explains why.

**UPDATE #2:**

The code I'm trying to replace currently looks something like this, with nested loops in shell.  At present, awk is *only* being used for its `printf`, and could be replaced with a shell-based `printf`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r fmtid fmt; do
  while read cid name addy; do
    awk -vfmt="$fmt" -vcid="$cid" -vname="$name" -vaddy="$addy" \
      'BEGIN{printf(fmt,cid,name,addy)}' > /path/$fmtid/$cid
  done < /path/to/sampledata
done < /path/to/fmtstrings
```

Example input would be:

```
## fmtstrings:
1 ID:%04d Name:%s\nAddress: %s\n\n
2 CustomerID:\t%-4d\t\tName: %s\n\t\t\t\tAddress: %s\n
3 Customer: %d / %s (%s)\n

## sampledata:
5 Companyname 123 Somewhere Street
12 Othercompany 234 Elsewhere
```

My hope was that I'd be able to construct something like this to do the entire thing with a single call to awk, instead of having nested loops in shell:

```
awk '

  NR==FNR { fmts[$1]=$2; next; }

  {
    for(fmtid in fmts) {
      outputfile=sprintf("/path/%d/%d", fmtid, custid);
      printf(fmts[fmtid], $1, $2) > outputfile;
    }
  }

' /path/to/fmtstrings /path/to/sampledata
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, both because of the actual topic of this question and because I haven't yet figured out how to elegantly make awk join $2..$n into a single variable.  (But that's the topic of a possible future question.)

FWIW, I'm using FreeBSD 9.2 with its built in, but I'm open to using gawk if a solution can be found with that.

Comment: In the larger context that inspired the question, are you going to have multiple input lines representing multiple format strings (so that `printf` will be invoked many times with the same data but different format strings), or are you going to use a single format string (that happens to be read from a file) throughout the `awk` program? It's a bit hard to devise a plausible use for the first scenario, but testing different format options might be a valid use case.  This matters because evaluating once can be done many ways; evaluating multiple inputs each as a format string is harder.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - added update #2 which better demonstrates what I'm currently doing and what I'd actually like to see as a result.  It's a bit of a balancing act to find enough of an example to demonstrate the problem while keeping back enough detail that it doesn't uselessly overburden the question.

Comment: @Graham I just updated my answer to include a fairly concise way to expand the escape chars within a single awk command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why so lengthy and complicated an example? This demonstrates the problem:

```
$ echo "" | awk '{s="a\t%s"; printf s"\n","b"}'
a       b

$ echo "a\t%s" | awk '{s=$0; printf s"\n","b"}'
a\tb
```

In the first case, the string "a\t%s" is a string literal and so is interpreted twice - once when the script is read by awk and then again when it is executed, so the `\t` is expanded on the first pass and then at execution awk has a literal tab char in the formatting string.

In the second case awk still has the characters backslash and t in the formatting string - hence the different behavior.

You need something to interpret those escaped chars and one way to do that is to call the shell's printf and read the results (corrected per @EtanReiser's excellent observation that I was using double quotes where I should have had single quotes, implemented here by \047, to avoid shell expansion):

```
$ echo 'a\t%s' | awk '{"printf \047" $0 "\047 " "b" | getline s; print s}'
a       b
```

If you don't need the result in a variable, you can just call `system()`.

If you just wanted the escape chars expanded so you don't need to provide the `%s` args in the shell `printf` call, you'd just need to escape all the `%`s (watching out for already-escaped `%`s).

You could call awk instead of the shell `printf` if you prefer.

Note that this approach, while clumsy, is much safer than calling an `eval` which might just execute an input line like `rm -rf /*.*`!

With help from Arnold Robbins (the creator of gawk), and Manuel Collado (another noted awk expert), here is a script which will expand single-character escape sequences:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
function expandEscapes(old,     segs, segNr, escs, idx, new) {
    split(old,segs,/\\./,escs)
    for (segNr=1; segNr in segs; segNr++) {
        if ( idx = index( "abfnrtv", substr(escs[segNr],2,1) ) )
            escs[segNr] = substr("\a\b\f\n\r\t\v", idx, 1)
        new = new segs[segNr] escs[segNr]
    }
    return new
}

{
    s = expandEscapes($0)
    printf s, "foo", "bar"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst2.awk <<<"hello: %s\nworld: %s\n"
hello: foo
world: bar
```

Alternatively, this shoudl be functionally equivalent but not gawk-specific:

```
function expandEscapes(tail,   head, esc, idx) {
    head = ""
    while ( match(tail, /\\./) ) {
        esc  = substr( tail, RSTART + 1, 1 )
        head = head substr( tail, 1, RSTART-1 )
        tail = substr( tail, RSTART + 2 )
        idx  = index( "abfnrtv", esc )
        if ( idx )
             esc = substr( "\a\b\f\n\r\t\v", idx, 1 )
        head = head esc
    }

    return (head tail)
}
```

If you care to, you can expand the concept to octal and hex escape sequences by changing the split() RE to

```
/\\(x[0-9a-fA-F]*|[0-7]{1,3}|.)/
```

and for a hex value after the `\\`:

```
c = sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" rest_of_str))
```

and for an octal value:

```
c = sprintf("%c", strtonum("0" rest_of_str))
```

Comment: One possibility, more gruesome than recommended, is to write an `awk` function like `function map_escapes(s,   t) { t = s; gsub(/\\n/, "\n", t); gsub(/\\t/, "\t", t); …; return t; }` and use that to manipulate the format string that's read from file.  You can extend it to handle other escape sequences as needed.

Comment: @mklement0, actually FreeBSD's awk does not need a space after `-v` at least in 9.2 and 10.0 which I have here.  What version of FreeBSD are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - therein be nasal demons as you need to worry about what to do if `\\n` etc. are already present in the input, you can't simply escape `\n`s.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I like that much better than spawning a `/bin/printf` in a subshell!  :)  But ... WHY does that work?  What's the difference between `\t` and `\t`?!?

Comment: That's partly why I said 'gruesome'.  Actually, as long as the rules of engagement are clearly understood (which may be tricky), then converting a string with escapes into one without escapes is mechanical and deterministic (though maybe not using the `gsub()` mechanism shown in my possible implementation, come to think of it — or now you point out the problem with multiple backslashes).  The point I'm making (to the OP more than to you) is that `awk` allows you to write functions and mapping the string may be the best way to get around the problem.

Comment: @Graham: The difference between `\t` and `\t` depends on the context where it is interpreted.  In the data file, you have two consecutive characters, backslash and `t`.  When reading from the file, `awk` reads those two characters and treats them as two characters.  In the `awk` source code (script, program), you have two consecutive characters, backslash and `t`.  When reading the program, `awk` interprets the two characters as a notation for the single character tab, and it uses a tab while it is running.  This is the crux of your problem.

Comment: @Graham: My proposed function would, if implemented correctly (which means 'not using `gsub` as originally suggested'), do the transformation on the input string that `awk` does on its source code.

Comment: @EdMorton you think your code is safer than eval think again: `echo '$(rm -rf /)' | awk '{"printf \"" $0 "\" " "b" | getline s; print s}'` Please don't do it on  your system :)

Comment: @Graham: Ah, good point: more recent versions of FreeBSD `awk` indeed do NOT need the space (e.g., `version 20121220`). I had naïvely assumed that the version on _OS X_ (as of OS X 10.9.4) is current, which is not true: it is `version 20070501`. So the general statement is: _Older_ versions of FreeBSD `awk` - such as the one in OS X 10.9.4 - need a space after `-v`.

Comment: @EdMorton try this: `echo '$(whoami)' | awk '{"printf \"" $0 "\" " "b" | getline s; print s}'`

Comment: @EdMorton How's that safer? Alright, a challenge try to do something nasty with the perl one line I suggested.  I already managed to break yours :)

Comment: But I don't care. I'm not suggesting the printf is completely safe, just that it's safer than an eval. If you disagree and want to use the eval, go for it and feel free to let us know or not when you hit that problematic case.

Comment: OK, BTW the problem is not `printf` the problem is `|` or even `system()` they can't be done blindly.

Answer (score 3):

Ed Morton shows the problem clearly (edit: [and it's now complete, so just go accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577032/1290731)): awk's string literal processing handled the escapes, and file I/O code isn't a lexical analyzer.

It's an easy fix: decide what escapes you want to support, and support them.  Here's a one-liner form if you're doing special-purpose work that doesn't need to handle escaped backslashes

```
awk '{ gsub(/\\n/,"\n"); gsub(/\\t/,"\t"); printf($0 "bar\n", "world"); }' <<\EOD
hello:\t%s\n\tfoo
EOD
```

but for doit-and-forgetit peace of mind just use the full form in the linked answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question explicitly asks for an awk solution, here's one which works on all the awks I know of. It's a proof-of-concept; error handling is abysmal. I've tried to indicate places where that could be improved.

The key, as has been noted by various commentators, is that awk's `printf` -- like the `C` standard function it is based on -- does not interpret backslash-escapes in the format string. However, `awk` does interpret them in command-line assignment arguments.

```
awk 'BEGIN  {if(ARGC!=3)exit(1);
             fn=ARGV[2];ARGC=2}
     NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]="fmt="substr($0,length($1)+2);
             ARGV[ARGC++]="fmtid="$1;
             ARGV[ARGC++]=fn;
             next}
     {match($0,/^ *[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+/);
      printf fmt,$1,$2,substr($0,RLENGTH+1) > ("data/"fmtid"/"$1)
     }' fmtfile sampledata
```

(
What's going on here is that the 'FNR==NR' clause (which executes only on the first file) adds the values (`fmtid`, `fmt`) from each line of the first file as command-line assignments, and then inserts the data file name as a command-line argument. In `awk`, assignments as command line arguments are simply executed as though they were assignments from a string constant with implicit quotes, including backslash-escape processing (except that if the last character in the argument is a backslash, it doesn't escape the implicit closing double-quote). This behaviour is mandated by Posix, as is the order in which arguments are processed which makes it possible to add arguments as you go.

As written, the script must be provided with exactly two arguments: the formats and the data (in that order). There is some room for improvement, obviously.

The snippet also shows two ways of concatenating trailing fields.

In the format file, I assume that the lines are well behaved (no leading spaces; exactly one space after the format id). With those constraints, `substr($0, length($1)+2)` is precisely the part of the line after the first field and a single space.

Processing the datafile, it may be necessary to do this with fewer constraints. First, the builtin `match` function is called with the regular expression `/^ *[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+/` which matches leading spaces (if any) and two space-separated fields, along with the following spaces. (It would be better to allow tabs, as well.) Once the regex matches (and matching shouldn't be assumed, so there's another thing to fix), the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set, so `substr($0, RLENGTH+1)` picks up everything starting with the third field. (Again, this is all Posix-standard behaviour.)

Honestly, I'd use the shell `printf` for this problem, and I don't understand why you feel that solution is somehow sub-optimal. The shell `printf` interprets backslash escapes in formats, and the shell `read -r` will do the line splitting the way you want. So there's no reason for awk at all, as far as I can see.

Comment: +1 for this solution but I firmly believe in what you wrote in the end **Honestly, I'd use the shell printf for this problem** Why force something to `awk` which it cannot handle. It is really simple to do this directly in shell.

Comment: +1 for an ingenious pure `awk` solution; however, `$3` in `substr($3,RLENGTH+1)` should be `$0`, and `"data/"fmtid"/"$1` needs parentheses around it to make FreeBSD `awk` on OS X 10.9.4 happy. As for why you would want to use `awk`: performance (looping over lines in pure shell code is sloooow). Honestly, among the `awk`-based answers, my own still strikes me as the simplest while being equally robust.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for the eagle eyes. Fixed both errors. Indeed, your solution has merit; reading the datafile only once is better, since the order of inner/outer loop is irrelevant once the output is directed to individual files. Had I seen it in the noise, I probably wouldn't have written this one, but then this solution does show how to do line splitting.

Comment: Thanks, @rici. In addition to demonstrating line splitting, your solution is noteworthy for the dynamic rewriting of ARGV (which I didn't know could be done), which, while not the most efficient approach in _this_ case, may come in handy in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

[@Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577032/45375) explains the problem well.

A simple workaround is to:

- **pass the format-string file contents via an `awk` variable**, using command substitution,
- assuming that file is not too large to be read into memory in full.

Using GNU `awk` or `mawk`:

```
awk -v formats="$(tr '\n' '\3' <fmtStrings)" '
     # Initialize: Split the formats into array elements.
    BEGIN {n=split(formats, aFormats, "\3")}
     # For each data line, loop over all formats and print.
    { for(i=1;i<n;++i) {printf aFormats[i] "\n", $1, $2, $3} }
    ' sampleData
```

Note:

- The advantage of this solution is that it works generically - you don't need to anticipate specific escape sequences and handle them specially.
- On FreeBSD `awk`, this *almost* works, but - sadly - `split()` still splits by newlines, despite being given an explicit separator - this smells like a bug. Observed on versions `20070501` (OS X 10.9.4) and `20121220` (FreeBSD 10.0).
- The above solves the *core problem* (for brevity, it omits stripping the ID from the front of the format strings and omits the output-file creation logic).

Explanation:

- `tr '\n' '\3' <fmtStrings` replaces *actual* newlines in the format-strings file with `\3` (`0x3`) characters, so as to be able to later distinguish them from the `\n` escape sequences embedded in the lines, which `awk` turns into actual newlines when assigning to variable `formats` (as desired).
  `\3` (`0x3`) - the ASCII end-of-text char. - was arbitrarily chosen as an auxiliary separator that is assumed not to be present in the input file.
  Note that using `\0` (`NUL`) is NOT an option, because `awk` interprets that as an *empty* string, causing `split()` to split the string into individual characters.
- Inside the `BEGIN` block of the `awk` script, `split(formats, aFormats, "\3")` then splits the combined format strings back into individual format strings.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called templating. I would suggest that shell tools are not the best tools for this job. A safe way to go would be to use a templating library such as [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) for Perl, or [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for Python.

Comment: +1 for a look at the bigger picture. Template Toolkit comes with its own CLI, while Jinja2 does not, but there are third-party packages; e.g.: https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli (with `pip`, install via `[sudo] pip install j2cli`).

Answer (score 1):

I had to create another answer to start clean, I believe I've come to a good solution, again with perl:

```
 echo '%10s\t:\t%10s\r\n' | perl -lne 's/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg; printf "$_","hi","hello"'  
        hi  :        hello
```

That bad boy `s/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg` will translate any meta character I can think of, let us take a look with `cat -A` :

```
echo '%10s\t:\t%10s\r\n' | perl -lne 's/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg; printf "$_","hi","hello"'   | cat -A
        hi^I:^I     hello^M$
```

PS. I didn't create that regex, I googled unquote meta and found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.perl.misc/LSdUAeBUkx0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the non-interpretation of the special characters `\t` and `\n` by `echo`: it makes sure that they are understood as as-is strings, and not as tabulations and newlines. This behavior can be controlled by the `-e` flag you give to echo, without changing your awk script at all:

```
echo -e "hello:\t%s\n\tfoo" | awk '{s=$0; printf(s "bar\n", "world");}'
```

tada!! :)

EDIT:
Ok, so after the point rightfully raised by Chrono, we can devise this other answer corresponding to the original request to have the pattern read from a file:

```
echo "hello:\t%s\n\tfoo" > myfile
awk 'BEGIN {s="'$(cat myfile)'" ; printf(s "bar\n", "world")}'
```

Of course in the above we have to be careful with the quoting, as the `$(cat myfile)` is not seen by awk but interpreted by the shell.

Comment: The \n is no longer a part of the format once you use it this way; it becomes a record separator.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Chrono, and that becomes very tricky then to use keep on usign `echo` to pass the pattern...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as Chrono indicated, this isn't the correct solution, as (1) it isn't doesn't address awk's interpretation of the string (consider that input will actually be coming from a file, not `echo` as in the tiny example), and (2) it breaks the format strings into multiple lines.  For example, a format string of `hello: %s\nworld: %s\n` would not work, as the second `%s` would not be part of the format.

Comment: Okay, so per your edit, imagine that `myfile` has multiple lines, each of which is a format string that needs to be interpreted by awk.  Now what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This looks extremely ugly, but it works for this particular problem:

```
s=$0;
gsub(/'/, "'\\''", s);
gsub(/\\n/, "\\\\\\\\n", s);
"printf '%b' '" s "'" | getline s;
gsub(/\\\\n/, "\n", s);
gsub(/\\n/, "\n", s);
printf(s " bar\n", "world");
```

1. Replace all single quotes with shell-escaped single quotes (`'\''`).
2. Replace all escaped newline sequences that appear normally as `\n` with the sequence that appears as `\\\\n`. It would suffice to use `\\\\n` as the actual replacement string (meaning `\\n` would print if you printed it), but the version of gawk I have messes things up in POSIX mode.
3. Invoke the shell to execute `printf '%b' 'escape'\''d format'` and use awk's getline statement to retrieve the line.
4. Unescape `\\n` to yield a newline. This step wouldn't be necessary if gawk in POSIX mode played nicely.
5. Unescape `\n` to yield a newline.

Otherwise you're left to call the gsub function for each possible escape sequence, which is terrible for `\001`, `\002`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Graham,

Ed Morton's solution is the best (and perhaps only) one available.

I'm including this answer for a better explanation of WHY you're seeing what you're seeing.

A string is a string.  The confusing part here is WHERE awk does the translation of `\t` to a tab, `\n` to a newline, etc.  It appears NOT to be the case that the backslash and `t` get translated when used in a `printf` format. Instead, the translation happens at *assignment*, so that awk stores the tab as part of the format rather than translating when it runs the printf.

And this is why Ed's function works. When read from stdin or a file, no *assignment* is performed that will implement the translation of special characters.  Once you run the command `s="a\tb";` in awk, you have a three character string containing no backslash or `t`.

Evidence:

```
$ echo "a\tb\n" | awk '{ s=$0; for (i=1;i<=length(s);i++) {printf("%d\t%c\n",i,substr(s,i,1));} }'
1       a
2       \
3       t
4       b
5       \
6       n
```

vs

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{s="a\tb\n"; for (i=1;i<=length(s);i++) {printf("%d\t%c\n",i,substr(s,i,1));} }'
1       a
2               
3       b
4
```

And there you go.

As I say, Ed's answer provides an excellent function for what you need.  But if you can predict what your input will look like, you can probably get away with a simpler solution.  Knowing how this stuff gets parsed, if you have a limited set of characters you need to translate, you may be able to survive with something simple like:

```
s=$0;
gsub(/\\t/,"\t",s);
gsub(/\\n/,"\n",s);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's a cool question, I don't know the answer in awk, but in perl you can use `eval` :

```
echo '%10s\t:\t%-10s\n' |  perl -ne ' chomp; eval "printf (\"$_\", \"hi\", \"hello\")"'
        hi  :   hello
```

PS. Be aware of code injection danger when you use `eval` in any language, no just eval any system call can't be done blindly.

Example in Awk:

```
echo '$(whoami)' | awk '{"printf \"" $0 "\" " "b" | getline s; print s}'
tiago
```

What if the input was `$(rm -rf /)`? You can guess what would happen :)

---

ikegami adds:

Why would even think of using `eval` to convert `\n` to newlines and `\t` to tabs?

```
echo '%10s\t:\t%-10s\n' | perl -e'
   my %repl = (
      n => "\n",
      t => "\t",
   );

   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      s{\\(?:(\w)|(\W))}{
         if (defined($2)) {
            $2
         }
         elsif (exists($repl{$1})) {
            $repl{$1}
         }
         else {
            warn("Unrecognized escape \\$1.\n");
            $1
         }
      }eg;

      printf($_, "hi", "hello");
   }
'
```

Short version:

```
echo '%10s\t:\t%-10s\n' | perl -nle'
   s/\\(?:(n)|(t)|(.))/$1?"\n":$2?"\t":$3/seg;
   printf($_, "hi", "hello");
'
```

Comment: This is exactly what is needed, and it is exactly what awk lacks.

Comment: That's a code injection attack just begging to happen.

Comment: Looking forward to the first input file that contains `rm -rf /*.*` :-)

Comment: Of course `eval` in any language is dangerous, however there are ways to avoid code injection, but it would make the answer too lengthy