# Perl eval, awk system() getline. Both have security issues, Is one safer than another? why?

Tags: bash, perl, security, awk

In the question below:

[In awk, how can I use a file containing multiple format strings with printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576011/in-awk-how-can-i-use-a-file-containing-multiple-format-strings-with-printf/24577225#24577225)

OP is trying to get format from STDIN, which is indeed an unusual thing. Although unusual I took it as a challenge, but couldn't get it working with `awk`. I managed to get it working with  `perl` which offers `eval` known for security issues and code injection.

On that question it was suggested by a user with very high reputation that:

```
echo "a\t%s" | awk '{"printf \"" $0 "\" " "b" | getline s; print s}'
a   b
```

was safer than:

```
echo "a\t%s" | perl -lne ' chomp; eval "printf (\"$_\", \"b\")"'
a   b
```

I was able to expose the security issue in awk as below:

```
echo '$(whoami)' | awk '{"printf \"" $0 "\" " "b" | getline s; print s}'
tiago
```

But I was unable to do such thing in perl:

```
echo '`whoami`' | perl -lne ' chomp; eval "printf (\"$_\", \"b\")"'
`whoami`
```

Whatever I tried I didn't manage to get `whoami` executed.

So back to my question, I know they both have security issues but is any of them safer than than the other? If so why?

On that perl one-liner is there a way to get `whoami` executed?

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that using single quotes in the printf command is much safer than using double quotes and allows for safely quoting the input to avoid these problems.

Comment: Excellent point @EtanReisner, it should be single instead of double quotes in that expression: `echo '$(whoami)' | awk '{"printf \047" $0 "\047 " "b" | getline s; print s}'`.

Comment: @ikegami did you copy/paste EXACTLY the command line I posted or did you try to re-type it, possibly adding a semi-colon or something before the `"b"`?

Comment: Try puting parentheses around the print statement: `{("printf \047" $0 "\047 " "b") |`. You SHOULDN'T need that but... Otherwise - does your shell have a printf function?

Comment: @Ed Morton, `echo \''$(whoami)'\' | awk '{("printf \047" $0 "\047 " "b") | getline s; print s}'` outputs `ikegami`. Tested on both the machine where your original command works (`gawk`) and on the machine where it doesn't (`mawk`).

Comment: @ikegami Yes, using single quotes is not enough to protect you. You also need to escape any single quotes in the input. `gsub("'", "'\\''")` or so.

Comment: I also ran into the `mawk` not working problem. `mawk` and `nawk` apparently have precedence issues here. Storing the command in a variable and using `var | getline` also works with them.

Comment: @ikegami yes, it will NOT be foolproof. The question is, is it more secure than an eval? Also, always say if youre using mawk as it is a minimal-featured awk optimized for speed over functionality so we should not expect it to behave like other modern awks.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Re "always say if youre using `mawk`". I didn't know. I even mentioned my lack of knowledge in this area. I never heard of `mawk` or `gawk` before today. I was just used Ubuntu's `awk`. `mawk` claims to follow a similar standard as `gawk`. "`mawk` conforms to the Posix 1003.2 (draft 11.3) definition of the AWK language". "[`gawk`] conforms to the definition of the language in the POSIX 1003.1 Standard."

Comment: @Ed Morton, Re "The question is, is it more secure than an eval?" And the answer is, of course, not at all. It can execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @Tiago - I notice you changed from `$(whoami)` in the awk example to `\`whoami\`` in the perl example. I just tried it and with the former the output is `10513 545 10513whoami)` so I expect that's why you changed but I can't imagine why that'd be the output - any ideas?

Comment: @Tiago: This is irrelevant to your question (I think the answer is "neither of them is safe") but the eval is easily avoided in the problem you refer to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576011/in-awk-how-can-i-use-a-file-containing-multiple-format-strings-with-printf/24583289#24583289 . As usual, the key is constructing command-line arguments in an array instead of forcing an evaluation of the arguments; doing that in awk is just a little trickier.

Comment: @EdMorton That output is because `perl` is treating `$` as its own variable. I changed to "`whoami`" because it's how command substitution works in perl, but anyway it was just a matter of giving it the right syntax  and whoami gets executed.

Comment: @EdMorton `perl -e 'print $('` gets the output you mentioned. Apparently `$(` is related to gid of the proccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is passed to `eval` to be compiled and executed:

```
printf ("...", "b")
```

The following would execute `whoami` and display its output:

```
printf ("%s", `whoami`, "", "b")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So passing `` %s", `whoami`, " `` to that Perl program will cause it to execute `whoami` and display its output.

```
$ echo '%s", `whoami`, "' | perl -lne ' chomp; eval "printf (\"$_\", \"b\")"'
ikegami
```

---

A safe way to call `printf` using `sh`: (I don't know `awk`.)

```
# "$line" (with quotes) escapes as it interpolates.
echo "a\t%s" | sh -c 'read -r line ; printf "$line" "b"'
```

A safe way to call `printf` using `perl`:

```
# The multi-arg form of system bypasses the shell.
echo "a\t%s" | perl -nle'system "printf", $_, "b";'
```

Reimplementing `printf` using `perl`:

```
echo "a\t%s" | perl -nle'
   s/\\(?:(n)|(t)|(.))/$1?"\n":$2?"\t":$3/seg;
   printf($_, "b");
'
```

Comment: +1 for getting `whoami` executed so can  I  conclude they both are equally unsafe?

Comment: BTW how did you get that output if it compiles or not? tried `-Mstrict` and `-w` but didn't get that output.

Comment: @Tiago, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Tiago I believe he was just indicating what perl eventually evaluates not that he got perl to spit that out at him somehow.

Comment: That safe way with sed only works with a single `\t` in the input. More than one and it fails.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, It probably just needed a `g`, but I removed the need for `sed` a few minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah, `g` seems to have made it work but the shell one is better.

Comment: @ikegami, I thought there was a switch or module which was printing what you indicated with regard to compiling, never mind..

Comment: No, but you could replace `eval` with `print`.

Comment: @ikegami take a look at this `s/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg` it can translate any meta, I found it @ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.perl.misc/LSdUAeBUkx0

Comment: Fails for virtually all multi char escapes (so it doesn't do what you say it does), and slows things down by loading the Perl compiler for every character that needs replacing!

Comment: @ikegami thanks for pointing this issue with multi char escapes, I never really came across them, which escapes are these? any reference?

Comment: @Tiago, Your asking for documentation for the formatting string accepted by the command line tool `printf`? Type `man 1 printf`. Also, [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SuSE+Linux%2Fi386+11.3&arch=default&format=html). Note the link to `printf(3)` at the bottom of the linked page for the extra information referenced earlier in the linked page.